# aws elastic beanstalk deployment error: 502 gateway error

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy a django application using `Django 4.2.6` on the latest platform that AWS EB has to provide: `Python 3.9 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.0.4`

After any try or redeploy I've been getting a 502 Bad gateway issue and I would appreciate some help in debugging this.

On the `web.stdout.log` file I see this log line:
`web[2059]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ebdjango.wsgi'`

which is confusing because I don't see anything I've done different than what's been suggested across the internet via blogposts and so on.

All my sourcecode is available here: https://github.com/kolharsam/assignment-practical-swe

These are the links I've been looking into:

- https://medium.com/@justaboutcloud/how-to-deploy-a-django3-application-on-elastic-beanstalk-python3-7-and-amazon-linux-2-bd9b8447b55
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html
- https://testdriven.io/blog/django-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Try adding this to your django.config file:
`option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango.wsgi:application`

Comment: I have tried with this and it doesn't help :/

Comment: Can you try replacing the value for `WSGIPath` with `ebdjango/wsgi.py`?

Comment: Nope. That didn't work either :/

Comment: First off, python paths use dots, not slashes, so you're ok with `ebdj.wsgi`. You need to debug what's happening on your server. I'd probably start by going through this tutorial to make sure what you're doing looks right; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html